# Not able to add "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForm" v11 reference to VS2012 project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, report-viewer2012

I was asked to migrate a WinForm application developed over Visual Studio 2008 
to Visual Studio 2012. One of the win-forms contains a Report Viewer component that is taking more time than I would have expected due to a Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForm dll reference I cannot import into the project.

These are the steps I did:

- Migrated the application, did some small adjustments.
- Rebuild project, some errors come out on the Error List pane, most of them already cleaned out.
- Remaining errors are related to SSRS and the Report Viewer.
- Error on the import statement "**Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms**" indicate the reference is no loaded into the project.
- Right click on the Project -> Add Reference... -> Assembly -> Extensions --> select Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms and click OK.

[image: Framework 4.5 Assemblies List]

- Saved the project, then the solution and closed Visual Studio.
- Open the solution once again. Not only the errors remains but the reference I selected on the Assemblies list appears as **unchecked**.
- Double verified the dll file exists on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\ReportViewer". The file is there and the version is the correct one.

Does anyone realize what's going wrong here? Suggestions and comments are welcome.

Thanks in advance.